# MagicalRecord and CoreData saving in different context error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

So I have some methods to save my settings in CoreData by using MagicalRecord. But then I am trying to do this, I get this error: `Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'settings' between objects in different contexts`

So here is my code:
This method is saving data by specific user, who is using programm now

```
-(void)saveSettingsFirst:(BOOL)first{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
        SettingsData *newData = [self settingsDataForCurrentUserInContext:localContext];

        //SettingsData *newData = [SettingsData MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
        newData.firstValue = @(first);
        NSLog(first ? @"saveSettings FIRST 0" : @"saveSettings FIRST 1");
        newData.settings = [[CacheManager shared] currentUserWithContext:localContext];

        NSLog(@"Settings one is saved");
    }];
}
```

This method is taking setting from CoreData for currentUser:

```
-(SettingsData*)settingsDataForCurrentUserInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{
    NSLog(@"In settingsDataForCurrentUserInContext");
    SettingsData *settings = [SettingsData MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"settings" withValue:[[CacheManager shared] currentUserWithContext:context]];
    return settings;
}
```

And finally method, who fetching userData for current user from CoreData:

```
-(UserData*)currentUserWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{
    UserData *persons = [UserData MR_findFirstInContext:context];
    if (persons!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Current user with context not nil value");
    }
    return persons;
}
```

I need help to recognize were is my mistake, because for me all it seems logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the default context when fetching your `SettingsData`. So, change:

`SettingsData *settings = [SettingsData MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"settings" withValue:[[CacheManager shared] currentUserWithContext:context]];`

to:

`SettingsData *settings = [SettingsData MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"settings" withValue:[[CacheManager shared] currentUserWithContext:context] inContext: context];`

(disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested for typo's)

Comment: Okey, it works! Thank you!
Can u explain or give link to read why did this works. Because I am already loading user with context and it successfully loading. But as I can see we need to search in same context, right?

Comment: Yes, always use the same context. If you check the MR code, you will see that our original line uses the default context. But you are passing a local context, so you should adjust for that.

Comment: See also here: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Fetching-Entities#finding-entities-in-a-specific-context

Comment: And glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information